# Setup a variable with 3 digits in shellscript

Tags: sh

Goal of the programme:

Given the following link: `http://uuu-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/tested/ppp/201613/testimage-pbo-01_uyt$xxx.jpg`
Download all the images where the variable is <=999 (NOTE the $xxx)

Ex:

```
http://uuu-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/tested/ppp/201613/testimage-pbo-01_uyt001.jpg
http://uuu-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/tested/ppp/201613/testimage-pbo-01_uyt002.jpg  ........ etc
```

So my code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
xxx=000
while [ $xxx -le 999 ]
do
  wget http://uuu-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/tested/ppp/201613/testimage-pbo-01_uyt$xxx.jpg
  xxx=$(( $xxx + 1 ))
done
```

How to fix that?

Comment: You don't really have a problem statement here. Code dump + "fix this" does not count.

Comment: Explain what needs to be fixed. In excruciating detail. Present any attempts you've made to solve it yourself. Do all this by editing the question. Do NOT do it in the comments

Comment: Also, try echoing your URL. You'll find the result informative.

Answer (score -1):

Use the connotation ${variable} to concatenate a variable into others values, if you just write a $variable, the shell will not know that you want receive the value from the variable

```
 wget http://uuu-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/tested/ppp/201613/testimage-pbo-01_uyt${xxx}.jpg
```

Comment: What about the literal dollar sign?

Comment: No it shouldn't, and neither should yours. You are both missing a literal dollar sign in the URL.